# How to know if a query succeeded?

Tags: c#, mysql

How can I know if the following `INSERT` query succeeded?

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO People (PersonName, dateAdded) VALUES (?name, NOW())", connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("name", Name));
MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I tried running `Reader.Read()` but only an empty string is returned. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use ExecuteReader if you're doing an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. Use ExecuteNonQuery instead, it'll return the number of affected rows.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html#connector-net-tutorials-sql-command

Answer (score 9):

You instead use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery):

```
int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (affectedRows <= 0)
{
    // Houston, we have a problem.
}
```

Keep in mind if you have triggers on the data, it may not reflect the actual number of rows you attempted to `INSERT`:

> You can use `ExecuteNonQuery` to perform any type of database operation, however any resultsets returned will not be available. Any output parameters used in calling a stored procedure will be populated with data and can be retrieved after execution is complete. For `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is `-1`.

In general, however, you will receive a [`MySqlException`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlexception.html) if your query encounters an error.

Answer (score 3):

Only use the SqlDataReader when you're queryng the data base, the SqlDataReader is a fast forward-only pointer, so only is recommended for Querying, use the  ExecuteNonQuery() method of the SqlCommand, for example as the next code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[QueryString]")) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SQL Command",conn)) {
        //here you return the number of affected rows
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An exception will be thrown if it fails. The exception object will typically contain information about what went wrong (e.g. "primary key violation" etc...).

Also, use `ExecuteNonQuery` for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. The returned value will contain the number of affected rows.